# How to receive an AirDrop text file in my SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to receive an AirDrop text file, originating from my Mac (osx 13.4), in my SwiftUI app on my iPhone. Using Swift 5.8, Xcode 14.3 for ios 16.

I have put this in my `Info.plist`

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key><array><dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key><string>AirDrop Text File Type</string>
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
  <string>Default</string>
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key><array> 
  <string>public.text</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
```

On my iPhone I can see my `TestApp` in the AirDrop menu, but I don't know how to receive the data.

I have this code, but I cannot get the `url`, or the data, or whatever I am supposed to
receive. How can I get the content of the file, or even just its url, so I can read it.

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

 var body: some Scene {
     WindowGroup {
         ContentView()
     }
 }

}

struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
     Text("testing")
   }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
     print("\n didFinishLaunchingWithOptions \n")  // <-- can see this
     return true
 }
 
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
     print("\n url: \(url) \n")  // <-- cannot see this
     return true
 }

// what other func do I need here


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI uses new `UIScene` based UI LifeCycle, so you have to stick to `UIScene` events to handle it.

You have two Options.

1. use `UISceneDelegate` proxy
   [`UISceneDelegate.scene(_:openURLContexts:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene)

In order to make `UISceneDelegate` proxy, implement `UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:configurationForConnecting:options:)` like below (where `SceneDelegate` is `NSObject` & `UISceneDelegate` but I recommand you to make it also conforms to `UIWindowSceneDelegate` and  `ObservableObject`.)

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        let configuration = connectingSceneSession.configuration.copy() as! UISceneConfiguration
        switch connectingSceneSession.role {
        case .windowApplication:
            
     
            // use this code to provide your AppDelegate instance to SceneDelegate
//            var info = connectingSceneSession.userInfo ?? [:]
//            info["proxyAppDelegate"] = self
//            connectingSceneSession.userInfo = info
            
            configuration.delegateClass = SceneDelegate.self
        case .windowExternalDisplay:
            fallthrough
        default:
            break            
        }

        return configuration
    }
```

In your `SceneDelegate`

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        // use this code to retrive the AppDelegate
        let appDelegate = session.userInfo?["proxyAppDelegate"] as? AppDelegate
        // use this codes to provide your SceneDelegate for later use in UIKit way
        var sessionInfo = session.userInfo ?? [:]
        sessionInfo["proxySceneDelegate"] = self
        session.userInfo = sessionInfo
        // use this to handle url actions like universal link
        connectionOptions.urlContexts


    }


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        // use this method to handle url actions performed by this scene
    }
```

If your `SceneDelegate` conforms to  `NSObject` and `ObservableObject` then SwiftUI inject your `SceneDelegate` as `EnvironmentObject` in your `View`.
If you provide your `SceneDelgate` to `UISceneSession.userInfo`. you can get that instance later by using `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes` or `UIApplication.shared.openSessions`

2. use SwiftUI URL event handler.

[`View.onOpenURL(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onopenurl(perform:))

Comment: thanks, the `.onOpenURL{...}` works well. I was looking in the wrong direction to implement this.

Comment: .onOpenURL is not working for me with iOS 17.  The txt file that is airdropped to another device keeps opening in Files app rather than opening in my app or giving option.

Comment: @alionthego same for me. I tried so many tutorials and none of them helped me open my file in my app. it keeps opening in the documents app

Comment: @GasperJ. 
Did you guys updated the info.plist with correct UTI options?
UTI configuration must be specified for the Operating system to recognize your application

Comment: I believe the ability to open airdrop with other applications is not longer allowed.  All airdrop will go to downloads in Files app.  I think this is really a step backwards.

Comment: @alionthego yes, the airdropped files go ALWAYS to the Files app. I can then  import that file to my app from the Files app. this is how it works on real devices. On a simulator, however, the imported file goes straight to my app when using dragging the file into the simulator window.

Comment: @Watermelon yes, I am pretty sure the UTI are correct. I even tried to launch one of my older apps, where AirDrop import worked fine for me when I was on iOS 16. I have iOS 17 now and those files are now being opened in the Files app

Comment: I’ve been working on this problem over the weekend and I cannot open the airdropped data in my app(it always opens in File app) even though I configured custom UTI… So there are no ways to open in the app on iOS17 devices right?